# How to save predicted values of H2O.GBM in an existing dataframe?

Tags: r, data.table, h2o, gbm

I have made an H2O model to predict the values of `varToBePredicted`:

```
data <- h2o.importFile(file)
split <- h2o.splitFrame(data, ratios = c(.70, .15))

gbm <- h2o.gbm(
  training_frame = split[[1]],
  validation_frame = split[[2]],
  x = c(setdiff(names(data), allExceptThis)),
  y = 'varToBePredicted',
  ntrees = 1000,
  max_depth = 2)

model_path <- h2o.saveModel(object = gbm, path = getwd(), force=TRUE)
```

When I print the `R2` of this program by

```
print(h2o.r2(h2o.performance(gbm, newdata=split[[3]])))
```

I get a `R2` value of `0.85`. But my question is: How can I add the predicted values of varToBePredicted to `data` (which is a `data.table`)? I want this so that I can plot the observed values vs the predicted values.

Comment: Assuming your results are in an object called `results`, please share the `dput(head(results))` and also `dput(head(data))` (your data.table).

Comment: voting to close as "too broad". Unfortunately, without toy data it's very difficult to help...

Answer (score 0):

```
as.data.frame(h2o.predict(gbm, newdata=split[[3]]))
```